# What happens when there are more than `concurrency` invocations for a fixed `maxInstaces` Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Gen 2 Firebase Cloud Function on which I have set the `minInstances` to 1, `maxInstances` to 1, `memory` to 8 GiB and `concurrency` to 1000. The function is triggered via HTTPS. I want to know what happens if there are 1001 simultaneous invocations of this function. Since the `maxInstances` is set to 1, it will not start a new instance. Is the 1001th request quietly dropped or is it queued and is handled when some of the currently running 1000 requests complete.

I couldn't find this information in the documentation and wanted to confirm here.

Comment: The behavior depends on how you invoke the Cloud Function. Some clients/protocols auto-buffers, others immediately reject (so that your application code can schedule a retry if needed). Can you update your question with how you invoke the Cloud Function?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The function is triggered via HTTPS requests. I have added this information to the question also.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency means handling a certain number of requests at the same time. So in your case instance will handle 1000 requests parallely. And remaining request will be queued and handled later.

As mentioned by @Frank van Puffelen, The behavior depends on how you invoke the `Cloud Function`. And also you can schedule retry config to handle failed requests.

### Update

As mentioned by @John Hanley, The request will be queued for 30 seconds. If there are no instances available an `HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests` error will be returned.

***Reference:*** https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#limit_the_maximum_number_of_instances_for_a_function

Comment: In my case, the function is triggered in response to HTTPS requests.

Comment: Add this information to your answer: The request will be queued for 30 seconds. If no instance becomes available an HTTP status `429 Too Many Requests` is returned [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd).

Comment: Thank you @John Hanley, For sharing additional information.